# VLC's stereo to mono downmixer filter

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm converting some video classes to audio only to save space and I used the VLC convert tool. I'd like to keep them as mono only so I chose the 1 channel option. I just noticed that there's an additional "stereo to mono downmixer" filter, which I forgot to apply for the files. Is it necessary to use it in order to convert to mono? What is the actual effect of such filter in the audio?

Comment: Thank you, I had the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you saved only the left audio channel then any audio that is only in the right audio channel will have been lost by simply dropping the second audio channel.

Downmixing will, as the name suggests, instead *mix* both channels *down* into one.

Depending on your source it may not matter, as many home recordings may simply have the same data in both channels and downmixing is therefore a waste of CPU time.

But if you have a true stereo recording with distinct audio in both channels then you should prefer downmixing so you at least don't lose those sounds.

Only you will be able to tell if your audio is distinct channels or common. You might be able to hear it, or you might be able to check a [spectrogram](https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/understanding-spectrograms.html) to see if there is a difference.

It is not absolutely "necessary" to use downmixing. It depends on your original audio and whether there is something in the second channel that you want to preserve.